# Google Places API - Details

Tags: javascript, jquery, httprequest, google-places-api

I am attempting to grab 2 details from a google place. Reviews and Rating. Problem is I can't seem to get the HTTP GET to return anything.

Here is my code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJz153jtgN1oYRQeG2PvY5sWc&key=MyAPIKey",
    type: "GET", /* or type:"GET" or type:"PUT" */
    dataType: "jsonp",
    data: {
    },
    success: function (placesRequest) {
        console.log(placesRequest);
    },
    error: function () {
        console.log("Your code sucks, fix the HTTP request");
    }
});
```

Error:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

[image]

If I click on the link in there it takes me to this:

[image]

Here is the [Google Docs Link](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details).

What I've done:

1. Set up my API Key.
2. Found my company Place ID: ChIJz153jtgN1oYRQeG2PvY5sWc

Any pointers or directions would be appreciated.

Comment: Google doesn't have CORS headers enabled for Places API web service, so you cannot call web service via AJAX request. You should use places library of Maps JavaScript API in order to solve the issue.  Just follow the answer of @Prasanth Ravi.

Answer (score 0):

Try the solution below fiddle,

https://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/yfawx50v/

```
function initialize() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
        zoom: 15
    });

    var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

    service.getDetails({
        placeId: 'ChIJz153jtgN1oYRQeG2PvY5sWc'
    }, function (place, status) {
        if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {

            // Create marker
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: place.geometry.location
            });

            // Center map on place location
            map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);

            // Get DIV element to display opening hours
            var opening_hours_div = document.getElementById("opening-hours");

            // Loop through opening hours weekday text
            for (var i = 0; i < place.opening_hours.weekday_text.length; i++) {

                // Create DIV element and append to opening_hours_div
                var content = document.createElement('div');
                content.innerHTML = place.opening_hours.weekday_text[i];
                opening_hours_div.appendChild(content);
            }
        }
    });
}

initialize();
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay first you need to see if any syntax erro then,

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJz153jtgN1oYRQeG2PvY5sWc&key=MyAPIKey
```

Copy and paste your ajax URL in browser and see if your network ip is allowed to use that api key,

if returns error like this,

```
{
   "error_message" : "This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key. Request received from IP address 223.255.255.255, with empty referer",
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
}
```

Then Probably its permission issue, other than that if success then you need to check your code.

Hope this Helps.